# How Can I edit format of JSON

Tags: java, json, pojo

Converted POJO classes to JSON using Jackson.

```
String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(Table 1);
```

I've JSON like below

```
{

    "id": #,
    "name":"name",
    "Table 2":[
        {
            "id": #,
            "name":"name",
            "Table 3":[
                {
                    "id": #,
                    "name":"name"
                }
            ],
            "Table 4":[
                {
                    "id": #,
                    "name":"name"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": #,
            "name":"name"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want JSON like

```
{

    "TableName":"Table 1"
    "id": #,
    "name":"name",
    "children":[
        {
            "TableName":"Table 2"
            "id": #,
            "name":"name",
            "children":[
                {
                    "TableName":"Table 3"
                    "id": #,
                    "name":"name"
                },
                {
                    "TableName":"Table 4"
                    "id": #,
                    "name":"name"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "TableName":"Table 2"
            "id": #,
            "name":"name"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I can edit format of json like this?
Thanks in advance..

My POJO class structure is like

```
Table 1.java
@JsonProperty("children")
private Set<Table2> Table2 = new HashSet<Table2>(0);

Table 2.java
@JsonProperty("children")
private Set<Table1> Table1 = new HashSet<Table1>(0);
//@JsonProperty("children") 
private Set<Table3> Table3 = new HashSet<Table3>(0);
//@JsonProperty("children")
private Set<Table4> Table4 = new HashSet<Table4>(0);

Table 3.java
@JsonProperty("children")
private Set<Table2> Table2 = new HashSet<Table2>(0);

Table 4.java
@JsonProperty("children")
private Set<Table2> Table2 = new HashSet<Table2>(0);
```

In Table 2.java, I want Table3 & Table4 under Children. 
But I cant use @JsonProperty("children") for both Table3 & Table4, they will be conflict between names.

```
"children":[
                {
                    "TableName":"Table 3"
                    "id": #,
                    "name":"name"
                },
                {
                    "TableName":"Table 4"
                    "id": #,
                    "name":"name"
                }
            ]
```

How we need to create Table 2.java POJO class here ?

Comment: Can you also share the pojo. The json will always depend on the structure of the object. You can't simply change the json

Comment: this may help you  http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 0):

Creating right POJO would solve your problem. You can create POJO like shown below

```
Class Table{
    String tableName;
    Long id;
    String name;
    List<Table> childrens;
}
```

Comment: In Table 2.java, I want Table3 & Table4 under Children. But I cant use @JsonProperty("children") for both Table3 & Table4, they will be conflict between names.How we need to create Table 2.java POJO class here ?